# How do I stop file types from launching automatically

Tags: applications

Is there a way to remove the 'open with' default that is on certain file types? I don't want to replace the the application that opens this file type, I want there to be no application assigned to that type, so that when I download it, no application automatically launches.

Basically is there a way to remove the default application a file type is opened with, and not replace it another application?

Answer (score 1):

That information is stored in the Launch Services database. The `lsregister` command can be used to manipulate that database. As far as I've been able to gather, you can only unregister an entire application, not an association for a specific file type. You can do that with this command:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -u /Applications/<appname>.app
```

But note that there is an automatic process in OS X that searches the /Applications folder and [registers the applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABEJFCD) it finds there. So if you have an application that wants to open a certain file type, the association might get recreated even if you have unregistered the application.

Someone may have a better answer than this but hopefully this will be at least a little helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are asking, but I think your solution is actually somewhere different.  I think you might be referring to setting in Safari preferences.  Open "Safe" files after downloading?

[image]

If you really want to remove the association follow steps at:  http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57326949-263/how-to-clear-custom-application-associations-in-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried associating a filetype with a certain application and then uninstalling / deleting that application?